# Как сделать так, что бы выводились все объекты и строки из файла pickle в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

**Как сделать так, что бы выводились все объекты и строки из файла pickle в python3?**

Код файла ввода:

```
import pickle


class Class:
    name = input('Введите имя: ')
    age = input('Введите возвраст: ')
    number = input('Введите номер телефона: ')

    total = [name, age, number]


f = open('data.pickle', 'ab')
pickle.dump(Class().total, f)
f.close()
```

Код файла вывода:

```
import pickle

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    storedlist = pickle.load(f)
    print(storedlist)
```

Какой должен быть вывод:

```
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
```

Какой настоящий вывод:

```
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
```

Помогите пожалуйста).

Comment: А почему вывод должен быть `['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']
['&&&', '&&&', '&&&']`
? Каков код, таков и вывод.

Comment: Вывод должен быть таким, так как я добавил в файл 3 значения, а не одно.